# reshape dictionary in python

Tags: tensorflow, dictionary, reshape

I have a dictionary with two keys and the shape for each of the two keys is ([612, 41, 41, 1]).
I would like to reshape it in order to have shape ([612, 41, 41, 2]) in order to feed it in the cnn with input channels = 2. If I use the command tf.expand_dims(my_dict[1], -2)} does not work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, because of 612x41x41x1 is different from 612x41x41x2 so you can't reshape to this shape. But if you mean that you want to duplicate the last dimension so you can try this code:

```
my_tensor = tf.tile(my_tensor, (1, 1, 1, 2))
```